# Meaning of sde.DEFAULT in data source path: sde.DEFAULT (user@server_name:database_name)

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, data-source, arcgis-enterprise

I've pulled some MXDs into ArcGIS Pro that are using data from a very old PostgreSQL (9.3) server. The database looks to be set up with an `sde` schema. I don't think it was actually implemented correctly though in that `sde` may have been used to load data at one time or another based on what I'm seeing.

In looking at the data sources through catalog view, I see two different path formats for different feature classes. One of them looks like this:

`sde@server_name:db_name\db_name.sde.feature_class`

The other looks like this:

`sde.DEFAULT (user@server_name:db_name)\db_name.data_loader_user.feature_class`

If it matters, the `user` and `data_loader_user` in the second path are not the same and neither of them are the `sde` user.

What is the significance of sde.DEFAULT in the second path?

I see it's related to versioning in my reading, but nothing really seems to describe it very well.

Perhaps the reason the first path doesn't include sde.DEFAULT is because it looks like someone erroneously used the `sde` user to load the data in the database.

Comment: `sde.DEFAULT` is the name of the default version in Esri's versioning model.